# Removing rows from a CSV and then output (download) with PHP

Tags: php, csv, simple-html-dom

I have an array:

```
$remove_rownumbers = array(1, 4, 7, 9, 2);
```

These are rownumbers, that i wish to remove from a loaded CSV in PHP.

Now Im thinking to go through the rows, with a counter and a in_array if statement like this:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($CSV_FILE, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1500, ",")) !== FALSE) {
       if(in_array($row, $remove_rownumbers) == false) // if its not in the remove array, keep it
       {
         // (...) the output part, where im echoing out each row by foreach($data ...)
       }
       $row++;
    }
}
```

But how can I take the echo outputted now and store it in a CSV correct again? And this way the row numbers that was in the array is not in this new one

I found a start of it something like:

```
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=output.csv');
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; 
$fp = fopen("php://output", "w");
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YLQAL8Hc here's a snippet.

Comment: Any good reason you aren't using a database like any sane person?

Comment: Nope don't have reason for that, but I really wish a solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to fopen() a new CSV file and get the handle but then it's simple:

```
$row = 1;

if ( ($handle = fopen($CSV_FILE, "r")) !== FALSE ) {

    while ( ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1500, ",")) !== FALSE ) {

        if ( in_array($row, $remove_rownumbers) == false ) {
            fputcsv($newFile, $data);
        }
        $row++;
    }
}
```

I forgot the bit where you'd want to download it.  Use a redirect header to the new file.

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/newfile.csv");
```

Comment: Hmm Im thinking that it should replace the data that are in the current handled csv file, so it removes from that csv without a newfile.csv is this possible

Comment: No, you can't read and write to the same file without getting in a one hell of a mess.  You could write the new file, delete the old file, rename the new file.